# Issues with sound board after neon upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, audio, kde, pulseaudio, kde-neon

Recently Ive finally upgraded my KDE neon to 5.19

All was fine and smooth except that after booting sound wanst working anymore. I have onboard sound on my motherboard, which is connected to my sound system, and also sound on my video board (nvidia GTX 1050 Ti) through HDMI, which I dont use (to be honest, I dont even know how that works). They are "Built-in Audio" and "GP107GL"

Going into System Settings/Audio/Advanced, I can both devices, but besides Built-in Audio, there are no profiles to choose, only one option: "Off"

I tried pulseaudio -k, but it changed nothing

Then I tried pavucontrol: on it, on the Configuration tab, on Built-in Audio, I can see these options:

```
Analog Stereo Input
Analog Stereo Output (unplugged) (unavailable)
Analog Stere Duplex (unavailable)
```

If I set it to "Analog Stereo Output (unplugged) (unavailable)", than sound is back, it works.

That would be a great workaround, except it dont stays that way: every time I reboot, I have to open pavucontrol and do the same again

Also, if I merely touch the sound cable, or even if my desktop get shaken a bit (if one of my cats jumps on it, for example), the system will switch the default sound output out of Built-in Audio again, sometimes to the HDMI audio, sometimes to "Dummy audio", sometimes to "No output device". And then I have to go into pavucontrol again and set that back, and than it works again. Which is very very annoying

Is pretty weird and I dont think is impossible theres some hardware issue going on there, but it was working perfectly before the system upgrade. It seems like pulseaudio is getting confused by hardware detection somehow

Anyway, Im kinda lost on what to try to solve this or how to investigate it further. I just want to force it to Built-in Audio and leave it that way. Any tips? Anyone ever had similar issues?

Any help would be much appreciated, this is driving me nuts

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse
```

and reboot your system. The pulse directory should be created afresh and you should have sound.

Comment: that does not solves my problem. please read the question, you will understand that the problem is not that I dont have sound.